# Installing graph-tool and aptitude dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, python, aptitude, dependencies

I'm trying to install [graph-tool](http://projects.skewed.de/graph-tool/wiki/GraphToolDownload).

I've changed `sources.list` with the "precise" repository option. I can now run `sudo apt-get install graph-tool`, but I get the message `graph-tool : Depends: libcairomm-1.0 but it is not installable`

I'm not sure how to install this specific package. Running `aptitude search libcairomm` gives me:

```
i A libcairomm-1.0-1                        - C++ wrappers for Cairo (shared libraries)         
p   libcairomm-1.0-1:i386                   - C++ wrappers for Cairo (shared libraries)         
i   libcairomm-1.0-dev                      - C++ wrappers for Cairo (development files)        
p   libcairomm-1.0-dev:i386                 - C++ wrappers for Cairo (development files)        
p   libcairomm-1.0-doc                      - C++ wrappers for Cairo (documentation)
```

To confirm that I don't need to install the i386 packages, I ran `uname -m` and got the output `x86_64`

So to me, it looks like I've installed anything that could possibly be related to this dependency.

How might I fix this dependency?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the maintainers of graph-tool have not updated the dependencies for graph-tool yet to reflect the updated version of `libcairomm-1.0-1`.

Things you can do:

- Compile it from source so you don't run into the case of missing or conflicting dependencies issues.
- Get the source package from the repository and manually edit the debian/control file to reflect the change and build the deb file yourself and install it using that.
- Or wait till they update the dependency.

Comment: If you are interested in doing the non-standard method (that is not to wait it out), ping me here in the comments. I'll try to guide you on that.